# Waterfall and agile approaches issue, and UML Vs rational rose

Tags: uml, analysis, object-oriented-analysis, waterfall, rational-rose

I'm stuck with these two questions and I didn't get any obvious answers. Can anyone help?

1. Comparison between Structural (Water Fall or classical) approach and Agile (UP-Object Oriented) approach.
2. What is UML & Rational Rose

Thanks

Comment: Try google.. Not really a programming question, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The UML is the Unified Modeling Language. It is a collection of diagrams, terms, profiles, etc. that one uses to design and develop complex systems and software. The UML is controlled by a standards organization, the Object Management Group (OMG).

IBM Rational Rose is one of many tools for building UML models. The problem with Rose is that it stopped with version 1.5 of the UML. There were some follow-on products (Rational refers to them as RSx).

[Source](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20080624174737AAXjPSG)

Comment: @AhmadBzour Sorry man i am up to this only . Not much good with them .

Answer (score 0):

To know about waterfall model use this link - http://www.ianswer4u.com/2011/11/waterfall-model.html#axzz29jMkFobF
To know about Agile use this link-> http://www.hsc.com/tabid/69/default.aspx

UML -> http://www.omg.org/gettingstarted/what_is_uml.htm

Rational rose is a software which is used to create UML diagram. i suggest you use smartdraw or Edraw in place of rational rose s/w.